# How can I upload an image

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload an image to a server, but I have no success.
Where is my mistake?

How can I send the image property?

Bitmap? byte[] array? image path?
I don't know

This is my code.
Please help me.

```
         try

        {
            Uri uri=data.getData();
            String[]projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagepath=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));

             cursor.close();

                    Bitmap yourSelectedImage=BitmapHelper.getBitmapFromPath(imagepath);

                Bitmap  bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

                 BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
                    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 3;
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath,options);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream); 
                    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

         final        String    encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);

                File f = new File(imagepath);


                      imageName = f.getName();

                        stringToConvert = yourSelectedImage.toString();
                        theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();

                             convertimage=BitmapHelper.getByteStringFromBitmap(yourSelectedImage);


                         new ImageGalleryBigPopup(ImageGalleryActivity.this, yourSelectedImage)
                            {
                                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                                protected void OnSave() throws JSONException {
                                     jArr = new JSONArray();

                                        jsonObject.put("FileName", imageName);
                                        jsonObject.put("FileContent", encodedString);
                                        jsonObject.put("UploadStatus", upstat);

                                     jArr.put(jsonObject);


                                    for(int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++)
                                    {
                                        //images.add(new ImageGalleryItem(jArr.getJSONObject(i)));
                                        saveImage(jArr.getJSONObject(i));
                                    }

                                };
                            };

        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                Log.d("GALLERY", e.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

this is my saveImage() function

```
private void saveImage( JSONObject jsonObject2) throws JSONException
{
    ImageGalleryItem galleryItem=new ImageGalleryItem(jsonObject2);


    operationType = "0";
    operationId = "45";
    showLoadingPopup();
    //fileName = Converter.encodeUrl(fileName);
    String url = String.format(UrlConfig.IMAGE_SAVE, operationType, operationId);
    new ConnectionHelper(ImageGalleryActivity.this,url,galleryItem.toString()) {

        @Override
        protected void OnSuccess(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hideLoadingPopup();
            Log.e("ON succes", response);




            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Resim Eklenmistir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            getList();
        }

        @Override
        protected void OnFail(Throwable error, String message) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hideLoadingPopup();
            Log.e("Throwable", error.toString());
            Log.e("message", message);

        }

        @Override
        protected void OnException(Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hideLoadingPopup();
            Log.e("Exception", exception.toString());

        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's more simple by using a library like [Ion by Koush](https://github.com/koush/ion)

You can use it this way:

```
Ion.with(getBaseContext())
    .load("http://your_destination_url")
    .uploadProgressHandler(new ProgressCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(long uploaded, long total) {
            // Your progress behaviour
        }
    })
    .setMultipartFile("name_file", "image/jpeg", new File(YourFile))
    .asJsonObject()
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
            // To do on complete upload
        }
    });
```